# Count distinct by link on sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to count distinct by the link between two columns.

Here is the example.

| rownum | type | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | a |
| 2 | A | b |
| 3 | B | b |
| 4 | B | c |
| 5 | C | c |
| 6 | C | d |

If I count distinct by type column, it returns 3. However, what I'd like to do is to consider rownum 2 and 3, 4 and 5 are not distinctive because they got the same value on id column.

To rephrase,

| type | array of id |
| --- | --- |
| A | a, b |
| B | b, c |
| C | c, d |

Since A and B got same b, and B and C got same c on their arrays, it would return 1 as a result.

I have no idea where to start. Would appreciate if I can get any hint or something.

Comment: Please show a working piece of code / SQL you wrote yet and give specific error messages or details you would like help about.
See MRE here: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What you really want to do is to walk through a graph.  BigQuery doesn't have direct support for recursive CTEs (the SQL standard method for handling this).  It does support looping in the scripting language which can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below:

you might use [STRING_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg)

```
WITH TMP_TBL AS 
(
   SELECT 1 AS ROWNUM, 'A' AS TYPE, 'a' AS ID UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,'A','b' UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,'B','b' UNION ALL
   SELECT 4,'B','b' UNION ALL
   SELECT 5,'C','c' UNION ALL
   SELECT 6,'C','d'
);

SELECT DISTINCT TYPE,N_ID 
FROM 
(
SELECT TYPE,STRING_AGG(ID)OVER(PARTITION BY TYPE) AS N_ID FROM TMP_TBL
)
```